# Python. Send Uploaded File To Remote Server

Tags: python

In My Flask App, i want to upload a file to a remote server.

i tried this code but i get an error

```
import subprocess 

import os

c_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
myfile = open(c_dir + '\\cape-kid.png')

p = subprocess.Popen(["scp", myfile, destination])
sts = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)
```

this was just a test file. there's an image in the same directory as my test python file. the error said:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\waite-ryan-m\Desktop\remote-saving\test-send.py", line 20,
>   in 
>       p = subprocess.Popen(["scp", c_dir + '\cape-kid.png', 'destination'])   File
>   "C:\Users\waite-ryan-m\Desktop\WPython\WinPython-64bit-2.7.12.1Zero\python-2.7.12.amd64\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 711, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)   File "C:\Users\waite-ryan-m\Desktop\WPython\WinPython-64bit-2.7.12.1Zero\python-2.7.12.amd64\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 959, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo) WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Consider tagging your question with `bash` as to get people with experience using scp, because I don't think you are using it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

With `open()` you open an file to read or write on it. What you want is to concatinate the string and use this as parameter for scp. Maybe the file you want to copy also doesn't exist - have you tried printing the path you constructed and checking it manually?
And have you defined `destination` anywhere? This message could also mean, that the system cannot find `scp`.

Comment: Thanks but i actually ended up using the paramiko framework. it was quick and easy. thanks again